# 'Must be variable name in the data set' error using survSsplit() function in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to implement `survSplit()` logic because I am running into an error:

> end' must be a variable name in the data set

I assumed it was a problem with the variables names in my dataset so I walked through an online example and ended up with the same problem.

(http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5902_03fb8841f4cc4a3889cb61bf33e490ac.html)

I used the data file `lung`:

```
lung.split1 <- survSplit(lung,cut=c(200,400,600),end="time",event="event",   start="start", id="ID", zero=0)
```

> Error in Surv(time, event) : Time variable is not numeric

Here is the data:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are specifying columns named `'event'`, `'start'`, and `'id'`. The `lung` data set doesn't have columns by those names (at least not the version built in to the `survival` package). From your picture it looks like you've added an `event` column, but I still don't see `start` or `id` as column names.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks.  That is funny that the example I was following specifically used that data set.